# will the data in the session get cleared if we switch route?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, authentication, session

We have 2 routes for user registration `/signup` and `/verifyOtp`.

Both routes are working fine in Postman and backend:

- the user email is getting verified by otp cross-checking
- the data is pushing to the database.

In the React frontend the first route is working fine, and data can be stored in the session. But in the second route, data cannot be extracted from the session and the console prints `undefined`.

```js
async verifyOtp(req: Request, res: Response): Promise < void > {
  try {
    console.log("user " + req.session.user)
    const otp = req.body.otp;
    console.log("otp................." + otp)
    console.log(req.session)
    const userData = req.session.user;
    console.log("session stored userdata :", userData)
    const email = userData.email;
    const password = userData.password;
    const name = userData.name;
    const phone = userData.phone;
    const otpCode = userData.otpCode;
    console.log("session............")
    if (otp === otpCode) {
      const user = await signup(email, password, name phone);
      res.status(201).json(user);
    } else {
      res.status(400).json({
        error: "Invalid otp !!"
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({
      message: "Server Error"
    })
  }
},
```

Comment: Kindly don't post code as images. [Refer](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) here for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

No, data stored in `sessionStorage` persists across page reloads and route changes within a single-page application (SPA) as long as the session is active.
`sessionStorage` is designed to store data for the duration of a page session.

##### If you reload the entire page, whether intentionally or unintentionally, the `sessionStorage` data will be cleared.

try to use other options like

- Cookies
- localStorage
- IndexedDB